# Declaring the datatype dynamically reading from an xml string

Tags: .net, serialization, dictionary, xml-serialization

I've this strange issue. I've an xml string which looks like below -

```
<key><int>5</int></key><value><int>10</int>
```

The above xml is obtained after serializing a Dictionary using [Paul's Code](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage). Now i want to convert the xml back to the dictionary.

How can i get the type "int" from the xml and declare the dictionary as follows?

```
Dictionary<int, int>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, I know, but here is a generic approach that works with a serialized SerializableDictionary (by one Paul, as you pointed out). If this is still pertinent, can you try it?

```
SerializableDictionary<int, int> stuffDict = ReadXML<int, int>(@"c:\test.xml");

private static SerializableDictionary<T, U> ReadXML<T, U>(string file)
{
    SerializableDictionary<T, U> dict = new SerializableDictionary<T, U>();

    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        FileStream flStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary<T, U>));
            dict = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(flStream) as SerializableDictionary<T, U>;
        }
        finally
        {
            flStream.Close();
        }
    }
    return dict;
}
```